# fsck from util-linux 2.26.2 get stuck after start machine

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, disk-check

I install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` 
Then I remove it with some of extra packages 
After restart computer stuck at this picture and I'm unable to boot Ubuntu or login 
If there's someway to fix it I will be thankful
If this helps , also have a windows 7 on the same computer(dual boot) and Ubuntu dvd [image: the problem]

Comment: `fsck` terminates normally, your problem is that nothing is executed after it. You have probably messed up your system, so you could just reinstall.

Comment: @fkraiem okay i can do a new install but i have some important files on it can i restore it ? as i say i have a windows 7 and ubuntu dvd any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is  when removeing ubuntu-gnome-desktop I delete some gnome packages used by unity-shell and ubuntu core
P.S Ubuntu can start normaly in recovery mode and upstart mode

---

to fix the broken packages see this [Ubuntu fix broken packages](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/)

---

(what I did)or simply you can boot the Ubuntu DVD and follow the installation but when prompt to select installation type select Reinstalling Ubuntu xx.xx

and this should repair the system and keep the files in home directory